# "Incremental" growth as growth by a minimum unit

Tags: meaning

I always thought that the literal meaning of "incremental growth" was growth by one, or by some minimum unit, that "to increment by one" would be redundant, and that other usages (for addition by things greater than one) were just colloquial.  But OED and other dictionaries I'm looking at all favor the definition that I thought was imprecise.  It's only OED's fourth meaning that even connotes the smallness of an increase; the others seem to allow an increase of any size.

Am I going crazy?  I needed that word. Does English have some other word for something growing or increasing by 1?

Comment: By one what?  Seriously.  If you're talking about number theory or computer programming, then their specialized languages may provide what you want (maybe even in the form of the word "increment").  If you're talking about measurements rather than numbers, however, then increasing by exactly one is meaningless unless you specify the units.  And if you're doing that, then the unit could as easily be "1000 bushels" as "one British pound".  The idea of increasing by exactly one runs into a bit of trouble here.

Comment: *unit increase*?

Comment: I always said this as `++` or the increment operator.  Not sure that counts as English.  I think of c, c++, java, c#, javascript, etc. as if they were foreign languages.

Answer (score 1):

I've always thought (well, in all my years since becoming literate) that an *increment* is an indefinite increase in size, weight, or quantity; that is, until the increment is quantified in some way. Whether small or large, increments are still increments. You can see, then, that I side with the OED.

As for one-word alternatives meaning an increase of one, I'm hard-pressed to
come up with one. Equally imprecise is the word *augment* (*augmented*, *augmentation*).

If, however, something increases by one, but only in the sense of doubling in size, you could use the words *one-hundred percent*. Just a thought.

As for other ways of speaking about an increase of one, you can also resort to using a specific rate/percent of increase. For example,

> From 1 to 2 is a 100 percent increase
>
> From 2 to 3 is a 50 percent increase
>
> From 3 to 4 is 66-and-two-thirds percent increase
>
> From 4 to 5 is a 25 percent increase
>
> From 5 to 6 is a 20 percent increase
>
> From 6 to 7 is a 16-and-two-thirds percent increase
>
> From 7 to 8 is approximately a 14.3 percent increase
>
> From 8 to 9 is a 12-and-one-half increase
>
> From 9 to 10 is approximately a 11.1 percent increase

Thereafter, the rate/percent gets progressively smaller, and very often the increase will be only approximate, since you have to choose the place (i.e., tenths, hundredths, thousandths, etc.) to which you are going to round up or down.

On the other hand, if you are talking about an increase from six million to seven million, the above rates/percents still apply. For example,

> From six million to seven million is a 16-and-two-thirds percent increase
>
> From two billion to three billion is a 50 percent increase
>
> From four million to eight million is a 100 percent increase

Finally, a *percentage* is not the same as a percent (even though newscasters habitually use the incorrect locution "X *percentage* points"). A percentage is an actual amount of something, whether dollars, cabbages, hamburgers, houses, or anything else.

For example, if you want to calculate the amount of your recent raise in salary as a percent or a percentage (assuming you went from $50K per annum to $75K per annum), you can say either

> I had a 25 percent increase in pay.

Or,

> I had a percentage increase of $25K in salary.

The above information comprises much more than you neither needed nor requested, but I'm feeling a bit magisterial at the moment, so . . ..

Answer (score 0):

*Incremental* has a few different uses. The one that normally applies to *incremental growth* has it functioning as the equivalent of rate of growth, but applied to a discrete time series such as a quarterly sales series. The incremental growth in quarterly sales is the change in sales from one quarter to the next. The thing being incremented is time, the thing being measured is sales. Growth just hangs a direction on the change.

A second use of *incremental growth* is when growth happens cyclically or in spurts. Tree rings reveal a pattern of incremental growth. In this case, it is the growth itself that is occurring in increments.

There are also many examples of loose usage where the writer uses *incremental growth* as a way to convey the idea of a persistent growth trend. "The incremental growth in water consumption continued throughout the decade in spite of conservation measures". Here it conveys a vague sense that the growth in water use is a stubbornly persistent trend and is immune to conservation efforts.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few different words at play here which you're getting mixed up, or perhaps just treating them as being the same, when they're not.

We have the **noun** *increment*, which just means *"a small increase, which is usually part of a series of increases"*.

We have the **verb** *increment*, which may just appear in computer science, and does indeed mean *"increase by 1"*.

We have the **adjective** *incremental*, which is just the adjectival form of the noun, ie a way of saying that a particular increase *is an increment* (noun).  Saying that an increase is incremental implies that it's part of a series of increases, eg that there will be a similar increase next year.

These are different words.  It's as simple as that.  You've encountered the verb and didn't know about the noun, by the sound of it.